# Changing a date field in a record using the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

I have an object stored in my database of type `time`. In the Rails console, if I find this particular record by its ID, I get the following output:

```
 id: 365,
 from_hours: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 01:00:00 UTC +00:00,
 to_hours: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 12:30:00 UTC +00:00
```

I'd like to update the `from_hours` field to `Sat, 01 Jan 2000 13:00:00 UTC +00:00`

How can I approach this?

I've tried using `MyRecord.find(365).update(from_hours: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 13:00:00 UTC +00:00)` to no avail. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are getting `from_hours: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 01:00:00 UTC +00:00` as a variable then use

```
MyRecord.find(365).update(from_hours: from_hours)
```

otherwise use the time inside quotes such as

```
MyRecord.find(365).update(from_hours: 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 13:00:00 UTC +00:00')
```

I would recommend not to use update directly because `record` can also return nil so better to use

```
if record = MyRecord.find(365)
  record.update(from_hours: 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 13:00:00 UTC +00:00')
end
```

Comment: I want the record to be of type `time`, though. Will putting that value in a string work that way?

Comment: Rails will take care of converting string to time, since the column type is of `time`

Answer (score 1):

you need to add quotes in the from_hours param:

```
MyRecord.find(365).update(from_hours: 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 13:00:00 UTC +00:00')
```

Use .update! if you need to get the raises exceptions in the console.